# How to inverse one hot Encoding for an output vector from AutoEncoder model ?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder, one-hot-encoding

I have a list of tokens as input. I have used One hot encoding to transform a text list into a binary encoded matrice. This matrice is then fed into a simple autoencoder architecture. The architecture is composed of 2 fully connected layers, folllowed by first part of this [link](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

In order to compare/ understand the result of this architecture, we need to inverse the one hot encoding transformation. This step is blocked by this error :

ValueError: y contains new labels: [121]

```
def getTokens(xml_string):
firstTagMatches = re.findall('(\<\w+\>)', xml_string, re.DOTALL)
closedTagMatches = re.findall('(\<\/\w+\>)', xml_string, re.DOTALL)
betweenTagMatches = re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', xml_string)
xmlTokens = firstTagMatches + betweenTagMatches + closedTagMatches
return xmlTokens
def oneHotEncoding(data):
values = array(data)
# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
return onehot_encoded
def invertOneHotEncoding(data,decoded_imgs):
values = array(data)
print('values', values)
print('type', type(values))
 # integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
print('integer_encoded', integer_encoded)
print('decoded images 1', decoded_imgs)
    # invert 
#final_decoded = np.zeros(shape= decoded_imgs.shape)
#for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(decoded_imgs):
#    if value > 0:
#        final_decoded[x,y] = 1
#print('decoded images 2', final_decoded)
inverted = [label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(decoded_imgs[i, :])]) for i in range(len(decoded_imgs))] 
#inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(final_decoded[0, :])])
return inverted
def getEncodedTrainingData(directoryPath):
#path = '/some/path/to/file'
encodedXML = np.zeros(shape=(0,166)) #because we know that the first file will give us a numpy array of shape=(166,166)
for filename in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    print('filename', filename)
    pretty_xml_as_string = ''
    trainingTokens = []
    xmlObject = xml.dom.minidom.parse(directoryPath+'/'+filename) 
    pretty_xml_as_string = xmlObject.toprettyxml()
    trainingTokens = getTokens(pretty_xml_as_string)
    transformedMatrice = oneHotEncoding(trainingTokens)
    dimensions = transformedMatrice.shape[0] * transformedMatrice.shape[1]
    onehotEncodedArray = np.resize(transformedMatrice, (int(dimensions/166),166)) #it may loose some information !! need a better solution
    print('onehotEncodedArray shape', onehotEncodedArray.shape)
    encodedXML = np.concatenate((encodedXML, onehotEncodedArray), axis=0)
print('before deleting shape', encodedXML.shape)
#encodedXML = np.delete(encodedXML,np.s_[0:166], axis=0) #remove the first initialized line
return encodedXML

encodedXML = getEncodedTrainingData('./trainingData/')
encodedXML_test = getEncodedTrainingData('./testingData/')
```

The machine Learning part :

```
#make the AutoEncoder Model
# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 32  
# this is our input placeholder
input_vector = Input(shape=(166,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu', 
activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_vector)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(166, activation='relu')(encoded)
# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_vector, decoded)
 encoder = Model(input_vector, encoded)
 encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
 # retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
 decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
 # create the decoder model
 decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
  autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy'])
 x_train = encodedXML
 x_test = encodedXML_test
 autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=50,
            batch_size=256,
            shuffle=False,
            validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
 # encode and decode some digits
 # note that we take them from the *test* set
 encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
 decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
 invertedSentence = invertOneHotEncoding(testDataTokens,decoded_imgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the inputs and outputs. Let's simplify this, assume there are 4 labels, then your `x_train = [[0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1]]` so you have 2 data points already one hot encoded. Now you can build your autoencoder as:

```
in = Input(shape=(num_classes,))
enc = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(in)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(enc)
```

Your network will have to predict one of the classes as a distribution based on the encoded vector. Given it's still a classification problem, you'll have `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss when training.

Comment: I have simplified the problem as requested but how can I inverse the one hot encoding of the predicted array (the output of the autoencoder model)

Comment: By the way I don't agree with the fact that I should use categorical_crossentropy since it is supposed to output 0 or 1. So it is binary classification.

Comment: You said autoencoder? So you will be predicting input labels which is 1 of many not a binary classification, it would be multi-label classification.

Comment: ah yes you are right ! but how can I output a matrice with 0 or 1 then ? because this matrice can be transformed with inverse one hot encoding

Comment: You don't output a prediction with 0-1 instead it is a probability distribution that predicts a particular label and you train with original labels.

Comment: So, how am I going to inverse one hot encoding to transform the decoded matrix to array of words ? I thought of including this in the invertOneHotEncoding function. Do you think that's a good idea ?

Comment: for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(decoded_vector):
       if value > 0:
           final_decoded[x,y] = 1

Comment: You take the argmax, so the highest probability of a word in that prediction becomes the predicted label.

Comment: I am doing that in this line of code if you have seen below 'inverted = [label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(decoded_imgs[i, :])]) for i in range(len(decoded_imgs))]' but I got the error that I have mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code works perfectly fine. The thing is that when I have trained the autoEncoder on my actual data, it was not enough data. So when I tested the autoencoder, the predicted vector was not exactly the test vector. That's why I got the ValueError Exception. In order to get the final decoded output, I have modified the 'invertOneHotEncoding' to have :

```
def invertOneHotEncoding(label_encoder,decoded_imgs):
inverted = []
for i in range(len(decoded_imgs)):
    try:
        print('decoded', label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(decoded_imgs[i, :])]))
        inverted.append(label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(decoded_imgs[i, :])]))
    except ValueError:
        inverted.append('<>')
return inverted
```

So I guess now, it makes sense why I got that error.